# How should I will get the position of the dynamic view in ANDROID

Tags: android, dynamic, view, position

Below is the view that I have created dynamically and I have added two rows but I can't get the position of that particular row, so I could I get it. I have created four textviews with one view, but how can I get the position of that particular view?

[image]

On click of a button I have added the code mentioned below,

```
private LinearLayout llAddMember;
llAddMember = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.llAddMember);
AddFamilyMemberModel familyMemberModel = new AddFamilyMemberModel();
                familyMemberModel.setStrMemberName(strMemberName);
                familyMemberModel.setStrGender(strGender);
                familyMemberModel.setStrMemberRelation(strMemberRelation);
                familyMemberModel.setStrMemberAge(strMemberAge);
                arrAddFamilyMember.add(familyMemberModel);

                LayoutParams lparams = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                llAddMember.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.white));

                TextView txtResMemberName = new TextView(RegistrationPatientActivity.this);
                txtResMemberName.setLayoutParams(lparams);
                txtResMemberName.setText("Member Name: " +familyMemberModel.getStrMemberName());
                txtResMemberName.setTypeface(Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"Roboto-Regular.ttf"));
                txtResMemberName.setTextSize(14);
                txtResMemberName.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#9C9C9C"));
                txtResMemberName.setSingleLine(true);
                llAddMember.addView(txtResMemberName);
                lparams.setMargins(50, 5, 40, 0);

                View view1 = new View(RegistrationPatientActivity.this);
                LayoutParams lparamsView1 = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 2);
                view1.setLayoutParams(lparamsView1);
                view1.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#DEDDDA"));
                llAddMember.addView(view1);
                lparamsView1.setMargins(50, 10, 0, 0);

                TextView txtResGender = new TextView(RegistrationPatientActivity.this);
                txtResGender.setLayoutParams(lparams);
                txtResGender.setText("Member Gender: " +familyMemberModel.getStrGender());
                txtResGender.setTypeface(Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "Roboto-Regular.ttf"));
                txtResGender.setTextSize(14);
                txtResGender.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#9C9C9C"));
                llAddMember.addView(txtResGender);
                lparams.setMargins(50, 10, 0, 0);

                View view2 = new View(RegistrationPatientActivity.this);
                LayoutParams lparamsView2 = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 2);
                view2.setLayoutParams(lparamsView2);
                view2.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#DEDDDA"));
                llAddMember.addView(view2);
                lparamsView2.setMargins(50, 10, 0, 0);

                TextView txtResMemberRelation = new TextView(RegistrationPatientActivity.this);
                txtResMemberRelation.setLayoutParams(lparams);
                txtResMemberRelation.setText("Member Relation: " +familyMemberModel.getStrMemberRelation());
                txtResMemberRelation.setTypeface(Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "Roboto-Regular.ttf"));
                txtResMemberRelation.setTextSize(14);
                txtResMemberRelation.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#9C9C9C"));
                llAddMember.addView(txtResMemberRelation);
                lparams.setMargins(50, 10, 0, 0);

                View view3 = new View(RegistrationPatientActivity.this);
                LayoutParams lparamsView3 = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 2);
                view3.setLayoutParams(lparamsView3);
                view3.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#DEDDDA"));
                llAddMember.addView(view3);
                lparamsView3.setMargins(50, 10, 0, 0);

                TextView txtResMemberAge = new TextView(RegistrationPatientActivity.this);
                txtResMemberAge.setLayoutParams(lparams);
                txtResMemberAge.setText("Member Age: " +familyMemberModel.getStrMemberAge());
                txtResMemberAge.setTypeface(Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "Roboto-Regular.ttf"));
                txtResMemberAge.setTextSize(14);
                txtResMemberAge.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#9C9C9C"));
                llAddMember.addView(txtResMemberAge);
                lparams.setMargins(50, 10, 0, 0);

                View view = new View(RegistrationPatientActivity.this);
                LayoutParams lparamsView = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 4);
                view.setLayoutParams(lparamsView);
                view.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#006D67"));
                llAddMember.addView(view);
                lparamsView.setMargins(0, 10, 0, 0);
```

Answer (score 1):

You're using a listview for this, right?

In your activity/fragment...

```
listview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        // do stuff ('position' is the position of the item you've clicked on)
    }
});
```

Comment: But he is not using ListView

Comment: No, I am not using any listview, as I have added my code above and for that I am using dynamic textviews to make it happen, but can't get the position for this view.

Comment: So you're adding views to some parent container? If so, you'd probably want to setTag on each view and then getTag when clicking on it. Not sure why you're doing this this way, wouldn't it make more sense to use a ListView for this and an xml layout (I don't see offhand why you'd want to programatically create your view)

Comment: Actually I have a scrollview and inside that I have taken the listview, but when I add the rows, the only one row will be added and if suppose I should start adding the second row, it won't be visible to that layout.

Comment: You've made a simple layout issue into a complex one ;). ScrollView containing a ListView is just asking for trouble. You'll save yourself a ton of headaches by implementing a ListView (or better, RecycleView) and inflating your rows via a simple xml layout. This will also easily solve your 'get position' problem ;)

Comment: I have implemented a dynamic view, so for that I only need to solve that issue rather than implementing a listview to my app.

Answer (score 1):

If you just have four view,you can set tag with position when create it.like this:

```
txtResMemberName.setTag(1);
```

and then you can get position by:

```
int pos = (Integer) txtResMemberName.getTag();
```

Comment: But I need the position of the whole row and that's where I have two rows as of now.

Comment: You can also set tag to llAddMember like I suggested.

Comment: Yes, that's what I did it already but can't get the position.

Answer (score 0):

As we have discussed above you have managed this View using LinearLayout ,this is not the right  approach to proceed , You need to implement this task using RecyclerView or ListView which is provided by default in Android . I would suggest you to go through this [Link](http://www.truiton.com/2015/02/android-recyclerview-tutorial/)

Answer (score 0):

I came to the conclusion for the above question and I have implemented it to my project and it works fine for me.

**I have created one main linearlayout and for that I have added those views to that layout and the lastly I have added that newly created view to my main linearlayout and hopefully it works.**

```
AddFamilyMemberModel familyMemberModel = new AddFamilyMemberModel();
                familyMemberModel.setStrMemberName(strMemberName);
                familyMemberModel.setStrGender(strGender);
                familyMemberModel.setStrMemberRelation(strMemberRelation);
                familyMemberModel.setStrMemberAge(strMemberAge);
                arrAddFamilyMember.add(familyMemberModel);

                LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                LinearLayout linearLayout = new LinearLayout(getApplicationContext());
                linearLayout.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
                linearLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

                LayoutParams lparams = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                linearLayout.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.white));

                TextView txtResMemberName = new TextView(RegistrationPatientActivity.this);
                txtResMemberName.setLayoutParams(lparams);
                txtResMemberName.setText("Member Name: " +familyMemberModel.getStrMemberName());
                txtResMemberName.setTypeface(Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"Roboto-Regular.ttf"));
                txtResMemberName.setTextSize(14);
                txtResMemberName.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#9C9C9C"));
                txtResMemberName.setSingleLine(true);
                linearLayout.addView(txtResMemberName);
                lparams.setMargins(50, 5, 40, 0);

                View view1 = new View(RegistrationPatientActivity.this);
                LayoutParams lparamsView1 = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 2);
                view1.setLayoutParams(lparamsView1);
                view1.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#DEDDDA"));
                linearLayout.addView(view1);
                lparamsView1.setMargins(50, 10, 0, 0);

                TextView txtResGender = new TextView(RegistrationPatientActivity.this);
                txtResGender.setLayoutParams(lparams);
                txtResGender.setText("Member Gender: " +familyMemberModel.getStrGender());
                txtResGender.setTypeface(Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "Roboto-Regular.ttf"));
                txtResGender.setTextSize(14);
                txtResGender.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#9C9C9C"));
                linearLayout.addView(txtResGender);
                lparams.setMargins(50, 10, 0, 0);

                View view2 = new View(RegistrationPatientActivity.this);
                LayoutParams lparamsView2 = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 2);
                view2.setLayoutParams(lparamsView2);
                view2.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#DEDDDA"));
                linearLayout.addView(view2);
                lparamsView2.setMargins(50, 10, 0, 0);

                TextView txtResMemberRelation = new TextView(RegistrationPatientActivity.this);
                txtResMemberRelation.setLayoutParams(lparams);
                txtResMemberRelation.setText("Member Relation: " +familyMemberModel.getStrMemberRelation());
                txtResMemberRelation.setTypeface(Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "Roboto-Regular.ttf"));
                txtResMemberRelation.setTextSize(14);
                txtResMemberRelation.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#9C9C9C"));
                linearLayout.addView(txtResMemberRelation);
                lparams.setMargins(50, 10, 0, 0);

                View view3 = new View(RegistrationPatientActivity.this);
                LayoutParams lparamsView3 = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 2);
                view3.setLayoutParams(lparamsView3);
                view3.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#DEDDDA"));
                linearLayout.addView(view3);
                lparamsView3.setMargins(50, 10, 0, 0);

                TextView txtResMemberAge = new TextView(RegistrationPatientActivity.this);
                txtResMemberAge.setLayoutParams(lparams);
                txtResMemberAge.setText("Member Age: " +familyMemberModel.getStrMemberAge());
                txtResMemberAge.setTypeface(Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "Roboto-Regular.ttf"));
                txtResMemberAge.setTextSize(14);
                txtResMemberAge.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#9C9C9C"));
                linearLayout.addView(txtResMemberAge);
                lparams.setMargins(50, 10, 0, 0);

                View view = new View(RegistrationPatientActivity.this);
                LayoutParams lparamsView = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 4);
                view.setLayoutParams(lparamsView);
                view.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#006D67"));
                linearLayout.addView(view);
                lparamsView.setMargins(0, 10, 0, 0);

                int pos = arrAddFamilyMember.size()-1;
                linearLayout.setTag(pos);
                linearLayout.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        int position  = Integer.parseInt(v.getTag().toString());
                        AlertDialogUtility.SHOW_TOAST(RegistrationPatientActivity.this, "Position: "+position);
                    }
                });

                llAddMember.addView(linearLayout);
```